# Qt resizing child widgets with the parent

Tags: c++, qt

I have made a custom widget in the UI designer which consists of the main window(which I resized to 700 width and 30 height) and inside it I have a QLineEdit that is 30 height and 770 width and next to it a [X] button that is 30 width and 30 height. I want to make it such that when the main window behind them is resized, the QLineEdit is resized too(horizontally), but the button always remains next to it. The problem is that right now when I resize the thing, the button gets obscured away.

Comment: You need to use layouts.

Comment: @tmoreau I dragged a horizontal layout on top of it and everything got confusing - I couldn\t select the widgets below it, so I had to remove them and add new ones on top of the layout, also once I added them on top of the layout, I couldn't adjust their sizes anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add a QHBoxLayout to your custom widget first and then add the QLineEdit and the QPushButton into the layout.

Layouts ensure that widgets stay properly ordered and resize correctly with the main widget.

It is also worth reading section "Adding Widgets to a Layout" in the [Layout Management documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Comment: the layout doesn't have any rezize options in the properties window, I have to drag it around manually? Also the widgets inside it also have their size options greyed out.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the stretch factor as outlined in the section of the documentation I pointed you to?

Comment: Ok I did everything and it looks OK in the Ui designer, however when I run the program, I get some small empty space allocated for the widget, but none of its contents show, just an empty space is pushed a bit. I checked the MOC code and everything looks fine, it creates the widgets, adds them to the layout, adds the layout to the main widget, but even after I call show() and try to resize to different sizes, it doesn't show.

Comment: This is not so easy to solve without seeing code. Feel free to edit your original question and show us the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: it seems that MOC failed, when I opened the generated file, I noticed it was creating some extra widget that is between the top widget and the layout with the rest of the children, I simply bypassed the middle widget(removed it) and set the layout to the top widget and now it works.

Comment: Good thing it worked! Can you accept the answer to close the question?